# `xdg-open` thinks I'm running WSL, and fails because I'm not?

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xdg, xdg-open

When I try to open a pdf file with `xdg-open file.pdf`, I get the following error message:

```
jonas@jonas-thinkpad:~$ xdg-open file.pdf 
grep: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop: No such file or directory
WSL Interopability is disabled. Please enable it before using WSL.
grep: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop: No such file or directory
[error] WSL Interoperability is disabled. Please enable it before using WSL.
jonas@jonas-thinkpad:~$ /usr/bin/wslview: line 216: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/reg.exe: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/wslview: line 308: [: -ge: unary operator expected
[error] This protocol is not supported before version 1903.
```

For some reason it tries to do WSL shenannigans? As I don't use Windows, I really don't understand why this happens. `xdg` seems to be configured to open pdf files with okular:

```
jonas@jonas-thinkpad:~$ xdg-mime query default application/pdf
okularApplication_pdf.desktop
```

And this is what `okularApplication_pdf.desktop` looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
MimeType=application/pdf;application/x-gzpdf;application/x-bzpdf;application/x-wwf;
Terminal=false
Name=Okular
Name[ar]=اوكلار
Name[az]=Okular
--- omitted languages ---
Name[zh_TW]=文件檢視_Okular
GenericName=Document Viewer
GenericName[ar]=عارض المستندات
--- omitted languages ---
GenericName[zh_TW]=文件檢視器
Comment=Universal document viewer
Comment[ar]=عارض المستندات عالمي
--- omitted languages ---
Comment[zh_TW]=通用文件檢視器
Exec=okular %U
Icon=okular
Type=Application
InitialPreference=8
Categories=Qt;KDE;Graphics;Viewer;
X-KDE-Keywords=PDF, Portable Document Format
X-KDE-Keywords[ar]=PDF, Portable Document Format
--- omitted languages ---
X-KDE-Keywords[zh_TW]=PDF, Portable Document Format
NoDisplay=true
```

Looks totally fine to me. Any clue what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, less than 5 minutes after asking the question I find the answer: For some mysterious reason, I had the package [`wslu`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/wslu) installed. A simple

```
sudo apt remove wslu
```

resolved the error.

Comment: Good find - Glad you caught this fairly quickly ;-).  Did you by any chance have `gimp-help-en` installed as in the other answer I linked?  Or do you think `wslu` got installed as a different dependency?  Regardless, it's a bug (and someone needs to report it at some point for any package which erroneously includes `wslu` as a dependency.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I don't think I installed anything gimp-related, not consciously anyway. When I removed `wslu` it didn't appear to have anything dependent on it. Though I had some trouble earlier with an unintentional `texlive` install I didn't want, not sure if that is related. Just guessing.